# Issue with Mounting a Volume in Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following problem. I am trying to mount a volume using docker-compose. When no volume is mounted, the container works perfectly fine. However, as soon as I attempt to mount a local directory to a path in the Docker container, the target path becomes empty, and the Docker container becomes corrupted. It appears as though the local folder is overwriting the folder in the container. This issue is not specific to a particular image; it affects other Docker containers as well. In Docker Desktop, the corresponding paths are listed under File Sharing. Here is an example file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  shop:
    container_name: Dev_shopware6
    image: dockware/dev:6.5.3.3
    ports:
      - "22:22"     # ssh
      - "80:80"     # apache2
      - "443:443"   # apache2 https
      - "8888:8888" # watch admin
      - "9998:9998" # watch storefront proxy
      - "9999:9999" # watch storefront
      - "3306:3306" # mysql port
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - web
    environment:
      - XDEBUG_ENABLED=0
```

```
Dev_shopware6 | AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html/public] does not exist
Dev_shopware6 | AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html/public] does not exist
```

Im working on MacOS with Docker Desktop

Projectstructure

```
.
├── docker
│   └── db
├── docker-compose.yml
├── readme.md
└── src

4 directories, 2 files
```

ls -la inside the container

```
www-data@63f6c46e9787:~/html$ ls -la
total 492
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Jul 18 15:49 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root     root       4096 Jul 18 15:49 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   1247 Jul 18 15:42 .env
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    647 Jul 18 15:42 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    369 Jul 18 15:42 .htaccess
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    350 May  3 10:38 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Jul 18 15:42 bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   1769 Jul 18 15:44 composer.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 415799 Jul 18 15:44 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Jul 18 15:42 config
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Jul 18 15:42 custom
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data    334 Jul 18 15:42 docker-compose.override.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   1070 Jul 18 15:42 docker-compose.yml
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Jul 18 15:43 files
-rw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data      0 Jul 18 15:43 install.lock
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Jul 18 15:43 public
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   6427 Jul 18 15:42 symfony.lock
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Jul 18 15:44 var
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   4096 Jul 18 15:44 vendor
```

Comment: Do you have a directory `src` in the directory where the `docker-compose.yml` resides?

Comment: @Turing85 yes the src folder is existing in the project dir

Comment: Can you please [edit] the post and add the directory structure, e.g. by running `tree` in the directory containing the `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: Looking at the error message it seems you need to bind mount `./src` on `/var/www/html/public/` instead of `/var/ww/html/`.

Comment: I added the structure to the topic

Comment: There is no directory `public` in `src`, hence there is no directory `public` in `/var/www/html`. I am not quite sure how to fix this; there seems nothing to be there that could be mounted.

Comment: What if just to create `public` directory manually?

Comment: Then you mount an empty directory.

Comment: Do /var/www/html/public/ contain any data you may need ones the container is up and running? Or you just want to create a development environment you wanto to control from your host? What is the pourpose of this container?

Comment: [Project](https://github.com/shopware/platform) Thats the expected structure i want to mount. If i didnt set the volume, the structure is in the container. If i set the volume, the whole directory is empty.

Comment: Ok, I following you now. Try to run the container without the mount first. Then do docker cp container:/var/www/html/ <the path of your src folder>. Then stop the container, add volume row once more. Now you should have src file with all project and you can work on it directly from your machine.

Comment: @KostyukRostyslav I want to create a dev environment to make changes from host.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mount-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container):

> If you bind-mount a directory into a non-empty directory on the
> container, the directory’s existing contents are obscured by the bind
> mount. This can be beneficial, such as when you want to test a new
> version of your application without building a new image. However, it
> can also be surprising and this behavior differs from that of docker
> volumes.

So basically, you can't bind mount a host directory on top of an existing directory in the image without 'hiding' the directory content in the image.

You mount your `./src` directory on `/var/www/html/` and that hides everything in `/var/www/html/` and below.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your replay in comments I assume you want to create a development environment for the project you have shared in the comment section.

You can do the following:

1. Run you container **without** the mount line
2. Run this [command](https://linuxhandbook.com/docker-cp-example/) `docker cp <container name>:/var/www/html/ ./src` (the path may vary based on your system)
3. Run you container **with** the mount line

This way you your src folder will have all the files from the original container. The [project](https://github.com/shopware/platform) you shared have public folder so everything should work well.

Comment: That works fine. It seemed to me as if my former projects had reacted differently. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean?